# How to run scala BDD tests in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, bdd, scalatest

I'm trying to run this sample BDD test [examples](http://www.scalatest.org/) in my Eclipse IDE, but seems that in Run Configurations there are not suitable propositions for that? Also I couldn't find any suitable perspective for that.

What I'm supposed to do to run that test in my Eclipse IDE?

I'm aware that I can run a test (or set of tests) with the command line, but is there some integrated solutions in the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Which test framework are you using? "BDD tests" is not enough information.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral  scalatest and specs probably. the examples link points to scalatest

Comment: @aishwarya I missed the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article](http://draconianoverlord.com/2009/09/10/scalatest-spec-from-eclipse.html) explains how to run scalatest tests in eclipse.